# html setting width and height using style tag does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a calendar with html and trying to set the width and height of each cell to 100. For this I tried using style tag as below. But for some reason, the height and width of each cell does not change. But instead of specifying the attributes in style tag, if I try to modify the individual cells with width/height attribute it works. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    td {color:green; width:100; height:100}
    th {width:100}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2">
 <caption> October 2012 Calendar</caption>
  <tr>
    <th> Sunday </th>
    <th> Monday </th>
    <th> Tuesday </th>
    <th> Wednesday </th>
    <th> Thursday </th>
    <th> Friday </th>
    <th> Saturday </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="grey"> &nbsp; </td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td background="../worldanimalday.jpg">4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...........................................................

Your css **problem** write **correct css** as like this

**Replace this css**

```
td {color:green; width:100; height:100;}
    th {width:100;}
```

**into this**

```
td {color:green; width:100px; height:100px;}
    th {width:100px;}
```